# IOS 7 GameCenter GKAchievementDescription incompleteAchievementImage

Tags: ios, game-center

I'm developing an IOS game using Game Center and while trying to design custom achievements UI i have a problem:
GKAchievementDescription has 2 methods for getting default achievement images:

```
+ incompleteAchievementImage
+ placeholderCompletedAchievementImage
```

(taken from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GameKit/Reference/GKAchievementDescription_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/GKAchievementDescription/incompleteAchievementImage)

These 2 methods work well on IOS 6, but on IOS 7 they return nil every time i call them. Has anyone encountered this problem and solved it?

Comment: I have this problem too.

Comment: Me too at least for `incompleteAchievementImage` on iOS 7.1.2.